Edit bibtex references so that the year appears after the author
I am having some difficulties formatting my references in a reportdocument.
The references should be formatted according to APA norms.
This is how I defined my references section:
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}

In APA norms, the year of a publication appears right after the name of the author.
Take for example this bibtex code for a reference:
@article{Bender2002,
  author  = {Bender B.},
  year    = {2002},
  doi     = {10.1067/mai.2002.124570},
  issn    = {00916749},
  journal = {Journal of Allergy and Clinical Immunology},
  month   = jun,
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {554--559},
  title   = {Overcoming barriers to nonadherence in asthma treatment},
  volume  = {109}
}

This is what it outputs in the list of references:

In addition to the year being displayed at the end of the formatted reference instead of after the author, the title should be in italics (and not the journal).
What can I do to change this, in the way that I want?
PS: you might be wondering why I didn't put the \bibliographystyle{apalike} (if that changes anything). I changed it to plain because I wanted the references to be displayed by number).

Off-topic: author = {Bender B.} is wrong. It should be either author = {B. Bender} or author = {Bender, B.}. Even better would be author = {Bruce G. Bender}; then, leave it to the bibliography style to determine whether the given name(s) should be truncated.

As plain and apalike were created more than 40 [!] years ago and have been essentially frozen ever since, neither bibliography style can produce citation call-outs and bibliographic entries that conform to current APA guidelines.

If you want to format your bibliographic entries according to current APA guidelines, also known as APA7, you should switch to biblatex (and to biber instead of BibTeX as the backend).

The somewhat older apacite citation management package and associated apacite bibliography style work with BibTeX, but they implement APA6 guidelines, not the more recent APA7 guidelines.



\documentclass{article}

% create a bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}
@article{Bender2002,
  author  = {Bender, Bruce G.},
  year    = {2002},
  doi     = {10.1067/mai.2002.124570},
  issn    = {00916749},
  journal = {Journal of Allergy and Clinical Immunology},
  month   = jun,
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {554--559},
  title   = {Overcoming barriers to nonadherence in asthma treatment},
  volume  = {109}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citet{Bender2002}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

